# SonarQube 6.4.0.25310 with TFS out of memory exception

Tags: sonarqube, tfs-2015, sonarqube-scan

I use the newest SonarBuild server and the SonarQube TFS extention 
(not the runner .bat) to build our .net applications,

[image: TFS Extention]

the builds runs on build-agents, and at some Projects i have got folowing **OutOfMemoryError** exception:, i read some threads about it already, where people writing something about inscrease or setup heap-memory of the Java runtime, but i don't understand how to do that, where i have to paste the options e.t.c. I have almost neither experience with java.

```
[error]Exception in thread "Report about progress of Javascript analyzer" Exception in thread "CHECKPOINT_WRITER" Exception in thread "CLEANUP_MANAGER" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[error]at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
[error]at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
[error]at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
[error]at org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport.run(ProgressReport.java:64)
[error]at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error]java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[error]at com.persistit.Persistit.closeZombieTransactions(Persistit.java:1706)
[error]at com.persistit.Persistit.cleanup(Persistit.java:1529)
[error]at com.persistit.CleanupManager.poll(CleanupManager.java:157)
[error]at com.persistit.CleanupManager.runTask(CleanupManager.java:88)
[error]at com.persistit.IOTaskRunnable.run(IOTaskRunnable.java:144)
[error]at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: as last i added **sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1280m** to the sonar.config file, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs on scanner side. You can try to increase memory of the scanner by setting environment variable `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1500m` prior to the end step. But the error likely come from the analysis of a big JavaScript file that is probably not your code but some third party library, and this could be solved by excluding those files from the analysis (using sonar.exclusions property on scanner side, of directly in the server UI).

Comment: can you tell me, how i can exclude the libraries using the sonarqube tfs extention?

Comment: Ok, i made it, now it runs.